# Using Lucene, how to index TXT files into different fields?

Tags: java, lucene

I am using the NSF data whose format is txt. Now I have indexed these data and can send a query and got several results. But how can I search something in a selected field (eg. title) ? Because all of these NSF data are totally plain txt file. I do not think Lucene can recognize which part of the file is a "title" or something else. Should I firstly transfer the txt files to XML files (with tags telling Lucene which part is "title")? Can Lucene do that? I have no idea how to split the txt files into several fields. Can anyone please give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

BTW, every txt file looks like this:
---begin---
Title:    Mitochondrial DNA and Historical Demography
Type:     Award
Date:     August 1, 1991
Number:   9000006
Abstract: asdajsfhsjdfhsjngfdjnguwiehfrwiuefnjdnfsd
----end----

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the text into the several parts. You can use the resulting strings to create a field for each part of the text, i.e. title.

Create your lucene document with the fields like this:

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("title", titleString, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
doc.add(new Field("abstract", abstractString, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
```

and so on. After indexing the document you can search in the title like this: `title:dna`

More complex queries and mixing multiple fields in the query also possible: `+title:dna +abstract:"some example text" -number:935353`